# JParsec - Scanner.string() equivalent for tokens

Tags: java, parsing, parser-combinators, jparsec

I have a parser for language that looks like this:

```
[nodeType OPTIONAL STUFF]
```

There are a few node typed, such as "ask" and "set", so currently `ask` and `set` are defined as keywords. This causes problems in other parts of the parser.

**Is there a way to define a token parser that accepts only tokens who contain specific text?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can have a look at the [Terminals](https://github.com/jparsec/jparsec/blob/master/jparsec/src/main/java/org/codehaus/jparsec/Terminals.java) class and this is also explained in the [Tutorial](https://github.com/jparsec/jparsec/blob/master/jparsec/src/main/java/org/codehaus/jparsec/Terminals.java).

Actually, jparsec combines the two passes of parsing that have been traditionally separated in lex and yacc: The lexical analysis phase (e.g. `Terminals`) parses a `String` and returns a stream of `Token`s, the syntactic analysis (other `Parser` instances) parses stream of `Token`s and interpret them, usually building an AST or embedding semantic directly.